# Why didn't Barry's father get a retrial after Joe and others witnessed the Reverse Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the episode *The man in the yellow suit* (S01, E09), we see that there is a small group of cops that Joey and Eddie bring along as backup.

So if these policemen witnessed the reverse flash why didn't Barry's father have a retrial?

Answer (score 6):

**Mainly because they do not have any solid evidence to connect the two.**

In the episode mentioned, Det. Joe does start to ask him about the night of Nora's murder. But Reverse Flash does not respond to it.

Also, they have no evidence placing him at the crime scene.

Throughout season 1, the reason Barry's father is still in prison, is because Barry & team do not have any evidence that would stand in a court of law.

**EDIT:** As of Season 2 Episode 1, Henry Allen is a free man. Harrison Wells made a confession as a part of his last will and testament, which got Henry's name cleared.